# git with or without ssl certificates

Tags: git, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have gitlab running on a server with a self-signed certificate, and I have configured git to use the certificate using

```
git config --global http.sslCAInfo path/to/cert.pem
```

This works fine.  However, a number of my projects use bower and when I do `bower install`, bower raises a SSL error connecting to github.  If I clear the certificate fform the config, bower works.

How do I tell git to use the self-signed certificate only for my gitlab domain, and to use default certificates for everything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I clear the certificate fform the config, bower works.

If you clear it, Git will look for CAs in  `<git>/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt` (which also contains PEM-formatted CAs, Base64 encoded ASCII files and containing "`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`" and "`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`" statements).

You could simply append your certificate to that file, and that would work for *all* remotes.

---

The [OP aquavitae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1235039/aquavitae) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822177/git-with-or-without-ssl-certificates/29822855#comment47774531_29822855):

> Not quite what I need because I'm on arch linux, but it pointed me in the right direction.
>   I needed to:
>
> - add my certificate to **`/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors`** and
> - run `trust extract-compat`

Comment: Not quite what I need because I'm on arch linux, but it pointed me in the right direction.  I needed to add my certificate to `/etc/ca-certificates/trust-source/anchors` and run `trust extract-compat`

Comment: @aquavitae OK. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.